# Expected blank line between class members

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:5000')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({ Shop: res.data })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members . You can disable this eslint rule or else you would need to keep an empty line between class members (*This rule improves readability by enforcing lines between class members.*)

Comment: Hi Ajeet, welcome to the site! Please make sure you don't just post the code in your question, but explain what's going on. I know you put the error message you're getting in the title but for people first seeing your question it's difficult to understand what exactly you want, because we only see a snippet of code without context. You can read more about how to write questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry @AjeetShah! You just edited it, my bad! This reviewing task is difficult...